# Select Comma Separator Column Data

Tags: mysql

I have data 1,2,3,1 like  one column 
in table

When i was display the these data in frond end
Stock column data its not taking space,
so wants select wit space for each value in stock

column`GROUP_CONCAT(msw_incoming_stock_detail SEPARATOR ', ')`

Comment: Please consider editing this question. It is difficult to make sense of it as it stands.

Comment: do you want add space after each ","?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace()`:

```
select replace(col, ',', ', ')
from table t
```